# Line-by-line userlist creation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to build a line-by-line userlist of random characters. Below I will explain what I wanna do.

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
```

I want a script that can create all posibilities until xxxx (4-digits).

Is there a way that I can do this via a bash script?

My OS is CentOS 7.0

Comment: `echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | tr " " "\n"` ?

Comment: @JID: `printf '%s\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}`

Comment: Please note that in case you use this mysql brute forcer script you've made, you should know that it's highly illegal to use on IPs that haven't given you permission to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
```

You can also use loop for getting the output in the format you desire by using following loop

```
for i in `echo {a..z}`; do for j in `echo {a..z}`;do for k in `echo {a..z}`; do for l in `echo {a..z}`;do echo $i$j$k$l;done; done ;done; done
```

The second one is the bad way to do it..

Comment: Your `\`echo {a..z}\`` is really useless.